# Google charts api- how to turn horizontal bars into vertical

Tags: google-visualization

I have read almost all of the possibly related docs with regards to my question but could not get appropriate answer for it.

I am using google visualization api to draw the bar chart. I am creating a datatable and adding columns and rows for that datatable. Finaly using the draw api on chart object and passing the datatable and options array like the following:

```
    var browser_options = {
                  width: 600,
                  height: 400,
                  legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
                    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
                           isStacked: true,

                 };
```

My question, i read from some google documentation that i can group my bar charts using chbh parameters. Is there a way I can set these parameters using draw api?

How do i turn my horizontal bars into vertical? These must be some properties that i need to set on chart's data right?

Any help is appreciated. If there is any documentation for google chart's set properties on datatable, please point me to that doc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure if I understood, but barchart is for horizontal bars and columnchart is for vertical ones

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `chbh` property applies to the Image Chart API, not the Interactive Chart API.  If you want to have vertical bars, you need to change your chart type from `BarChart` to `ColumnChart`, eg:

```
var myChart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
```

to:

```
var myChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Column chart]You can use Column chart instead of Bar Chart. Column Chart is like this .